# mysql: Query to find matches friends by custom search

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

I want to find matches friends by example ( city | age | gender | etc  )

user select to find friends from **form and html select**

age ( between 22 - 36 ) 
gender ( female )
city ( a , b , c )

my table like

```
---------------------------------------------
  member_id   |   member_key  | member_value    
---------------------------------------------
   2          |     city      |  a
---------------------------------------------
   2          |     gender    |  female
---------------------------------------------
   2          |     age       |  20
---------------------------------------------
   2          |     degree    |  5
---------------------------------------------
   3          |     city      |  x
---------------------------------------------
   3          |     gender    |  male
---------------------------------------------
   3          |     age       |  25
---------------------------------------------
   3          |     degree    |  3
---------------------------------------------
   4          |     city      |  a
---------------------------------------------
   4          |     gender    |  female
---------------------------------------------
   4          |     age       |  26
---------------------------------------------
   4          |     degree    |  3
---------------------------------------------
```

**and i want the result to be like this**

```
----------------------
member_id      |  match_count 
----------------------
4            |   3
----------------------
2            |   2
----------------------
3            |   1
```

I tried query like this but not working

```
SELECT `member_id`, `member_key`, SUM(
    CASE `member_key`
        WHEN ( "age" AND `member_value` BETWEEN 22 AND 36 )
        THEN 1
        WHEN ( "city" and `member_value` IN ("a","b","c") )
        THEN 1
        WHEN ( "gender" and `member_value` = "male" )
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END ) AS match_count
FROM members_info
```

i found this solution , it looks fine for me but performance :(

```
SELECT member_id,concat_ws(",",member_key) as match_in,count(member_id) as match_count
FROM members_info WHERE
  ( member_key = "age" AND member_value BETWEEN 22 AND 36) OR 
  ( member_key = "city" AND member_value IN ('a', 'b', 'c') ) OR
  ( member_key = "gender" AND member_value = "female" )
GROUP BY member_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I've understood what you try to accomplish.
This is another way that may be faster. I hope it runs smoothly :)

```
SELECT T.member_id, COUNT(*) AS affinity
FROM
    (SELECT member_id
    FROM members_info
    WHERE member_key = 'age' AND member_value BETWEEN 22 AND 36
    UNION
    SELECT member_id
    FROM members_info
    WHERE member_key = 'city' AND member_value IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
    UNION
    SELECT member_id
    FROM members_info
    WHERE member_key = 'gender' AND member_value = 'female') AS T
GROUP BY T.member_id
```

Comment: i had to add ( age | city | gender ) in quotes because unknown columns
and the result was all the table count 
not used our condition

Comment: can you help with success query

Comment: the quotes mean those are literals and not data from a table, so it doesn't make any sense. This is pretty straight forward, it looks like there's a deeper misunderstanding about how SQL works. Sorry to say that, but I have no idea how to help if you don't do your homework on your own.